# Transit visa not required at amsterdam

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, amsterdam, transit-visas

I had two tickets one from Mumbai to Amsterdam via Istanbul on Turkish airlines and Amsterdam to Quito on KLM airlines. Turkish airlines ground staff cleared me at Mumbai after verification of all documents and issued boarding passes.  At Istanbul, I was not allowed to board the flight to Amsterdam since I did not have Schengen visa. Indian passport holders don't need a transit visa at Amsterdam. Why did Turkish Airlines ground staff at Istanbul take such a decision?

Comment: Have you booked both the India->AMS and AMS->Quito flights on the same ticket? It doesn't really matter which airlines operate your flights. What does matter is that they are on the same ticket.

Comment: @DCTLib he passed through IST before AMS

Comment: I am sympathetic about this because I do connections across separate tickets quite often as well. I am not convinced that it is necessary that the flights be booked across the same ticket for the typical immigration regulations, although I will happily accede to an explicit statement of that fact.

Comment: I suppose you didn't have a visa for Canada, Japan or the USA either? See http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/index_en.htm

Comment: Did you happen to have a boarding pass for your flight departing from Amsterdam?

Comment: @Nemo That's not relevant, such visas would only exempt the OP from the *airside* transit visa requirement but Indian citizens don't need one in AMS in the first place. The crux of the matter is whether this could have been an airside transit or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the precision but what's the question, actually? Whether the decision was correct? How to avoid it in the future? How to get some redress? Whether someone else was able to do such transit at AMS?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you done something like that before? Since you had no checked bags, you did not need to physically pass immigration to collect them and might have been able to do an airside transit on two tickets. Since I live very close to Amsterdam I have never actually transited there but I assume it's possible to get a boarding pass from the transit desks inside the international transit area but I am not 100% sure… If that's the case then you were definitely correct and the staff in Istanbul made the wrong call.

Comment: I'm confused: what is the question here? There is a great discussion in the comments (where there should be, I might add) and a fabulous answer.. but what is the question?

Comment: Reverted the question to it's original state before deletion. @ram, if you wish to remove it, please delete the whole question, rather than just the question text.

Comment: @ram This is not a forum or customer line, the goal is to build a body of questions and answers that's useful to everybody. If you have got what you needed, it's all the more important to keep the question for others.

Answer (score 24):

You have made significant changes to your question since it was originally posted. In light of that new information:

Without checked baggage, you *could* have transited airside in Amsterdam. However, Turkish Airlines staff in Istanbul would have no way to know that you were planning to transit AMS and go elsewhere, unless you explicitly informed them. Since you say you *did* inform the staff of your other flight, I think this was a mistake and you should not have been denied boarding.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47397/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-hampton-transit-visa-not-required-at-amsterdam).

Answer (score 7):

Based on the information you have provided, you should NOT have been denied boarding of your flight.  You've stated that :

You had no plans to exit the airside part of the airport in Amsterdam, and as you were traveling with carry-on bags only there would have been no need to do so.

You had and showed the flight information for your connecting flight to the TK staff in Istanbul.

Your connecting flight departed the next day, but this was only ~16 hours later.

Additional facts that you haven't explicitly mentioned is that there is only one flight from AMS to Quito per day, being the one that you were booked on.

The Netherlands allows an Indian citizen to Transit Without Visa (TWOV) in the conditions that you've described above.

Timatic, which is generally the source that airlines use for visa requirements, states that :

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of
>   onward tickets transiting by the same or first connecting aircraft:

As you were transiting on the first connecting aircraft, you meet the exception and thus do not require a visa.

I suspect that the date difference confused the staff - the fact you were arriving into Amsterdam on one day and not departing until the next day is not allowed in some airport - however in Amsterdam is it, and there are even 2 airside hotels that you could have spent the night at without entering the country.

Comment: The fact that this person is eligible for TWOV is not relevant. They have two point-to-point journeys; and they do not have the proper documentation to continue their journey - since they need to enter the Schengen zone, in order to check-in for their onward flight (the final leg, on KLM). Based on this fact, Turkish airline is correct to deny boarding (in fact, they should have denied boarding from India).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  KLM has 5 transit desks at Amsterdam, as well as a huge number of self-service kiosks (which the OP may or may not have been able to use). There is no need to go airside to check-in, thus no need for a visa.

Comment: You know, I never saw one even when I was traveling to AMS from Kuwait on KLM! According to the airport diagram, the transfer helpdesk is in the arrivals plaza.